# why is this code giving segmention error in selection sort ,please explain

Tags: c, sorting, selection

why is it giving segmentation error please explain someone, I am new to competitive programming,  myself unable to find the error

Here is the code for selection sort :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int *xp ,int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp; 
}

void SelectionSort(int* A , int n)
{
    int i ,j ,imin;
    for(i =0 ; i<n-1;i++)
    {   
        imin =i;
        for (j =i+1;i<n;j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[imin])
            imin =j;
        }
        swap(&A[imin],&A[i]);

    }
}
int main()
{
    int A[]= {1,2,5,8,44,5,7,9,6};
    int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    SelectionSort(A,n);
    printf("start printing:");

    for(int i = 0;i<6 ;i++)
    {           
        printf(" output is %d  ",A[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop in `SelectionSort` has an issue:

```
for (j =i+1;i<n;j++)
```

means you are never testing `j`.  Try:

```
for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
```

Comment: it's unfortunate that the compiler doesn't complain about things like that

Comment: @AbdulAhad:  that's asking rather a lot of the compiler, you can't expect it to find logic errors.

Answer (score 0):

in for loop condition matching `j =i+1;i<n;j++` in this expression at place of `i`  use  `j` then loop will run otheswise not .